# Open a link of Excel with the dialog popup window in quick launch SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, excel

I have a Excel document in the Library SharePoint 2010. And I set **"Open in the client application"** in Library setting. Every time I open this document, there is a **popup window** with a question **"How would you like to open this file?"**
Then I can choose **Read Only** or **Edit**.
[image]

I copy the link of Excel to quick launch. But there is no popup window when I open this Excel from quick launch. Further more, **Excel is Read only**. I cannot edit it. And there is no button "Edit this workbook".
And my site is a publishing site, I cannot add JavaScript to quick launch.

At beginning, I though I can add the link of **"Open in the browser"**. But the members of team will make a mistake in this view. They would like use the popup window.

How could I open Excel document in quick launch with a dialog popup window? Is it possible to add JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following JavaScript for achieving this

```
var stsOpen = new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3");
stsOpen.ViewDocument3(window,"http://site/Library/Filename.xlsx",0,'');
```

If your site is non-publishing then you can place JavaScript in the Quick Launch. Check this blog http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-javascript-in-quick-launch.html

Comment: Hello Amal, the code is amazing ! It works well. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Amal  Is it possible to show the popup window like I posted in the question? I need **Edit** option. With your code, there is no Edit in popup. And Excel is always Read Only.

Comment: @Anna the code gives a pop-up as you posted in the question. Note this only works in IE.